# How to add a event in InAppBrowser, such that on exiting(exit event) the browser, the app should exit?

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins, inappbrowser

I wanted to add an event such that when a appBrowser is closed(exiting),exit or minimize the app.

Here is a code template to understand my query better

```
browser.on('exit').subscribe(() => {
           // minimize or exit app         
      });
```

I am using Ionic latest version(3+).
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

After researching a for long time, I got a solution:

use platform.exitApp(); method

so the code would become

```
browser.on('exit').subscribe(() => {
           platform.exitApp();         
      });
```

This method should be included in the ionic 3 docs. Found this function from v2 docs.